# How to override method of internally used class?

Tags: java, android

There is class `KeyboardView` in Android that uses internally class `Canvas`, and specifically method `Canvas.DrawText`. That method can draw only one line. I need it to draw two line.

It is possible in Java somehow to override `Canvas.DrawText`, so that `KeyboardView` will use overwritten method?

Is there any method to achieve requried behavior without full rewrite of `KeyboardView` from scratch?

Comment: Do you mean [this class](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java.shtml)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is actually another `Canvas` instance inside of `KeyboardView`, you'd have to extend the `KeyboardView` class directly. (`public class MyFancyKeyboardView extends KeyboardView`)

However, it looks like it has an implementation of the `View.onDraw(Canvas)` method that's called by the framework with an external `Canvas` provided. If you could wrap it inside of a `View` of your own, you might be able to provide your own `onDraw` that called the one for the `KeyboardView`.

```
     private KeyboardView wrappedKeyboardView;
     public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
         wrappedKeyboardView.onDraw (canvas);
         doMoreDrawing (canvas);
     }
```

(Keep in mind, of course, that every Android device is liable to have an entirely different keyboard layout, so I'm suspicious about drawing over it being particularly effective or portable…)

Comment: Regarding your comment about keyboard layouts: the KeyboardView class is a strange built-in used for custom keyboard-like components that define their own layout. It has nothing to do with the system keyboard. For example, its often used for calculator applications.

Comment: Bah, sorry, I misunderstood O:-) I haven't had to mess with it in any context. Just based my reply upon the class's signature & general guesswork…

Answer (score 1):

You would have to override the method of `KeyboardView` that instanciates the `Canvas` class to make it creating an instance of your class.

In the `KeyboardView` class, only the method `onBufferDraw` uses the canvas, and it instanciates it, too. Poorly, this method is very large.

Answer (score 1):

If the class doesn't provide a way to specify a Canvas subclass, or if it doesn't provide a behavioral extension point, then no, however: A *full* rewrite is not likely to be necessary, if you're aiming at specific functionality.

Instead, subclass the view, and re-implement only the functionality you need changed, and use your view subclass.